Get a webhook return from DF using Google Logs Explorer
I am trying to get a Webhook return that happens in Step 4 of Dialogflow CX
jsonPayload.queryResult.diagnosticInfo."Execution Sequence"."Step 4".FunctionExecution.Webhook.Status:"OK"
The problem is Step is dynamic, it can be "Step 4" "Step 5" "Step 11"
The filter works in Step 4 scenario, but how can I make it work without hardcode "Step 4"
Match the filter to know DF return without worry in which step it happens
